# Full Screen layout for in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm trying to run my test app on Simulator iPhone 5s and also my iPhone (also 5s ios 10) and it's not running with full screen although that I didn't change all the default setting, but when I run it on iPhone 6 Simulator it works just fine with full screen, where is the problem?

[image]

Extra Information:
the app is empty, I added only the launch screen for (ios8 iPhone Portrait, ios7 and later, ios6 and prior)

Comment: Do you have a launch image or a launch storyboard?  Use a launch storyboard

Comment: I found it, it caused by the wrong size of Retina 4 in LaunchImage,it works after I changed the size to  640 × 1136 pixels

Comment: That's why a storyboard is better. It resizes automatically

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you Paulw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be because of the wrong size of `Retina 4` in `LaunchImage`

It  will work when you changed it to `640 × 1136` pixels